# Build failure with Exec Maven plugin running a thor script

Tags: maven, thor, exec-maven-plugin

I have a simple thor script that copies resources to target directory from a submodule in my project. I have configured Exec Maven plugin to run the script at compile phase.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>thor</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>build:task</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My thor script runs fine when executed from a shell with **thor build:task** but for some reason my **mvn compile** fails with following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default) on project imsprocess: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default) on project imsprocess: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
```

Before the error message I can see my script printing messages and it seems to be working fine. Build completes without the exec plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that for some reason my thor script always returns with 1. I put these properties to Maven Exec plugin's configuration and now the build goes through without errors.

```
<successCodes>
    <successCode>0</successCode>
    <successCode>1</successCode>
</successCodes>
```

Comment: Could you tell me if this tag helps to have "fail on error" mechanism?